# Asynchronous Load JS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I am writing an application which is built moreover completely on JS. And due to that, I have huge number of JavaScript files. However, I don't wish to load all of them at my `index.html`, and just have one JS file, which will take care of loading other JS dependencies, before proceeding.

Something like `RequireJS`. But I don't want to use any other JS library or framework; not even JQuery, and have everything written in core Javascript.

How to achieve this? Is there something which I am getting wrong.?

Comment: My suggestion: look at how requirejs does it. It's open source, after all! And work from that.

Answer (score 1):

Note sure if this is what you are looking for but couldn't you do something like (http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml). If you want to load them at a particular time, just call the function when you are ready and set a delay using the setTimeout Function (setTimeout( function_reference, timeoutMillis );)

```
function loadjscssfile(filename, filetype){
 if (filetype=="js"){ //if filename is a external JavaScript file
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
 }
 else if (filetype=="css"){ //if filename is an external CSS file
  var fileref=document.createElement("link")
  fileref.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet")
  fileref.setAttribute("type", "text/css")
  fileref.setAttribute("href", filename)
 }
 if (typeof fileref!="undefined")
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
}

loadjscssfile("myscript.js", "js") //dynamically load and add this .js file
loadjscssfile("javascript.php", "js") //dynamically load "javascript.php" as a JavaScript file
loadjscssfile("mystyle.css", "css") ////dynamically load and add this .css file
```

Comment: its not about loading it at a particular time.. I just want one variable to have list of all JS dependencies.. and one function which will load those JS files.

Comment: The following code loads in javascirpt which would avoid your jquery loading problem. Not exactly sure what you want but maybe if you don't want to do that try: http://headjs.com/

Answer (score -1):

You can add the async attribute in the script tag to load a JavaScript file asynchronously. Something like this

```
<script src="app.js" async="true">
```

If you want the script to execute after the html page is loaded, you can use the defer attribute.

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)